# Copy some data from a database and keep referential integrity

Tags: mysql, transactions

The requirement is to extract some data from an active database (159 tables at the moment) into another database, such that the copied data has full referential integrity, whilst the data is in flux (it is a live database). This is not about dumping the entire database (approaching 50GB), just extracting some rows that we have identified from the whole database into a separate database.

We currently create a new DB based upon our initial schema and subsequent DDL migrations and repeatables (views, stored procedures, etc.), and then
copy the appropriate rows. This normally takes more than 10 minutes, but less than 1 hour, depending upon the size of the set to be extracted.

Is there a way to tell mysql that I want ignore any transactions committed after I start running the extract, be they new rows added, rows deleted, or rows updated, but any other connection to the database just carries on working as normal, as if I wasn't making any requests.

What I don't want to have happen is I copy data from table 1 and by the time I get to table 159, table 1 has changed and a row in table 159 refers to that new row in table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqldump --single-transaction`. This starts a repeatable-read transaction before it starts dumping data, so any concurrent transactions that happen while you are dumping data don't affect the data dumped by your transaction.

---

Re your updated question:

You can do your own custom queries in a transaction.

Start a transaction in repeatable-read mode before you begin running queries for your extraction. You can run many queries against many tables, and all the data you extract will be exactly what was currently committed as of the moment you started that transaction.

You might like to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Comment: I've updated the original question to more accurately reflect the requirement. We are not looking to dump the entire database (approaching 50GB), but to selectively copy  data for a key that is shared amongst the data (think a multi-tenanted database - we are extracting a single tenant).